# How to enable more detail in log for spring batch library

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-batch, compositeitemwriter, itemwriter

Good day,

I have a Spring batch, that using `org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter` to write data into db.

The following is the writer code in my xml:

```
    <bean id="iReturnCompositeTableWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>
                <ref bean="iReturnTableWriter5" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="iReturnTableWriter5" class="com.batch.job.writer.IReturnTableWriter">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="false" />
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <!-- Our Mapper for table writer -->
        <bean class="com.batch.job.writer.mapper.IReturnWriterTableMapper" />
    </property>
    <!-- Put in your INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE SQL here -->
    <property name="sql"
        value="UPDATE ADM.TRX
    SET  STATUS = 'FAIL'
        WHERE INTERNALREFERENCENO = :theirTraceNum" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

And the following is code of `IReturnTableWriter` class:

```
public class IReturnTableWriter extends JdbcBatchItemWriter< TrxVO >
        implements StepExecutionListener, ItemWriteListener< TrxVO > {

    public void afterWrite(List<? extends BulkPaymentVO> arg0) {
    }

    public void beforeWrite(List<? extends BulkPaymentVO> arg0) {
    }

    public void onWriteError(Exception arg0, List<? extends BulkPaymentVO> arg1) {
    }

    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution arg0) {
    return null;
    }

    public void beforeStep(StepExecution arg0) {
    }
}
```

And the following is the code of `IReturnWriterTableMapper` class:

```
public class IReturnWriterTableMapper implements
        ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider< IbgReturnVO > {

    public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(TrxVO trxVO) {
        return new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(trxVO);
    }
}
```

The batch log show this batch run successful without any error. The successful count is match with my input file row count. In the log, I also saw that its being read by the reader and store into `trxVO` object.

However, there is 1 of the record did not updated to database in production, even the success count is correct. I grab the input file and run in SIT, UAT and its working fine. From the log, I cant see it log about the update query.

I actually already enable log level to trace for `org.springframework.batch` and `org.springframework.jdbc` in logback.xml:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.batch">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>
```

And in log, I can saw its already take effect:

```
15:44:19,173 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.batch level set to TRACE
15:44:19,173 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.jdbc level set to TRACE
```

I would like to ask the way on how to enable more log for the writer, so that I can troubleshoot what is happening.

Or, if you have more useful idea, or suggestion, please advise.

Comment: if you can share the project, i can take a look

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask the way on how to enable more log for the writer

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` uses spring-jdbc APIs behind the scene, so you can set the log level to `debug` for `org.springframework.jdbc` package.

I would also enable debug logs for `org.springframework.batch` as well.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud, I actually did this, but nothing extra log come out :' (